# gcloud sql connect using access token got further but now fails when running psql

Tags: postgresql, gcloud

GCP recommends forcing SSL for database so I did.   Now, when trying to connect, I run

```
#This cmd is the same with other options too -> gcloud sql generate-login-token
gcloud auth application-default print-access-token > token.txt

gcloud sql connect instanceid --user=postgres --access-token-file=token.txt
```

but then this fails with psql needing certs (which I have on my machine but not sure how to supply).  It fails with this error

```
dean@Deans-MacBook-Pro database % ./connectMysql.sh
Allowlisting your IP for incoming connection for 5 minutes...done.
Connecting to database with SQL user [postgres].Password:
psql: error: connection to server at "xx.xxx.333.333", port 5432 failed: FATAL:  connection requires a valid client certificate
connection to server at "22.222.222.222", port 5432 failed: FATAL:  pg_hba.conf rejects connection for host "zz.yy.333.333, user "postgres", database "postgres", no encryption
```

I would like to use gcloud sql connect so it whitelists my ip each time as I move around alot and do not want to keep whitelisting ips and deleting them.